# xcode organizer refreshing provisioning profiles

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have had a look around and everyone seems to be having loads of different issues with the `xcode` organizer, but they don't seem to be having the same issue so I can't quite isolate my issue.

The issue I am having is when I go to the organizer and refresh the provisioning profiles it produces a message saying

> Sign in with your Apple ID

the username and password I provide are both correct but the window goes away and then immediately returns and doesn't say whether or not I enter correct details (I know they are correct) and it will continue asking me this for as long as it takes to refresh the profiles. This also happens when I select a device to use for development, but the device is never actually added to the team provisioning profile even though it says it has been.

Has anyone any idea how I can stop this?

Comment: I just tried this and it only asked me for my details once so I'm not sure what's causing the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Well it worked before I updated and now it is messed up. I am on the latest xcode.

Comment: @downvoter please give reason for downvote.

Comment: Not me - I upvoted. =)

Answer (score 2):

I guess in your position I would carry out the following checks:

1. Can you log in to your account on the Provisioning Profile. If
   you can then your Apple ID and password must be OK
2. When in Xcode and responding to the 'sign in' message are you
   using the username & password remembered by KeyChain? Are you sure
   these are both OK? Maybe enter them manually again to make sure
3. In Xcode go to the Provisioning Profiles screen in the Organiser
   tab and right-click a profile and select 'reveal in Finder'. Does
   the folder holding your local copies of provisioning profiles
   contain any extra files that might be old/corrupted versions? If so,
   delete them, return to Xcode and attempt to refresh again.
4. If the above three checks don't yield anything useful then I
   think it must be something corrupted on the provisioning profile
   (such as a provisioning profile or certificate) that needs to be
   revoked - letting Xcode create it/them anew for you. Or something
   out-of-date or corrupted locally (maybe a public or private key or
   certificate in KeychainAccess - a local copy of a provisioning
   profile). And you may have to start revoking/deleting digital assets
   to get things working again (but only do this if you have no other
   choices...)

I once had a horrible issue with an iPhone developer certificate that took ages to fix - but perseverance eventually paid off - good luck!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. I will check and let you know +1 for good detail.